# Torsion of simple abelian group extension

Tags: group-theory, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, group-extensions, torsion-groups

I'm curious if there is a general way to determine the torsion of a group extension. I'm most interested in the simple example where we have a central extension
$$ 1 \to \mathbb Z \xrightarrow{f} G \xrightarrow{g} \mathbb Z / n\mathbb Z \to 1,$$
where it is known that the map $f$ acts as multiplication by some integer.
What are the possible degrees of torsion elements in $G$? Furthermore, given the map $f$, is the torsion of $G$ determined? For example, if $f$ acts as multiplication by $n$, then $G$ must be $\mathbb Z$. On the other hand, if $f$ acts as multiplication by 1, then we have $G = \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/ n\mathbb Z$. Are there some simple general statements that can be made here?

Comment: $G$ can be ${\mathbb Z} \oplus {\mathbb Z}/m{\mathbb Z}$ for any divisor $m$ of $n$.

Comment: Is it possible for it to be other things, like $(\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z)/\sim$, where $\sim$ is some relation on the generators that doesn't make $G$ reduce to the direct sum you wrote down? And in the case where it is the direct sum, how does one determine $m$ given $f$?

Comment: I ask because $H^2(\mathbb Z_n; \mathbb Z) = \mathbb Z_n$ suggests that there are $n$ different central extensions, which tells us that not all choices of $G$ can be given by $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z / m \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Remember that while distinct, nonequivalent (nonisomorphic) extensions correspond to distinct elements of $H^2$, you can have distinct elements of $H^2$ corresponding to isomorphic (but not equivalent) extensions... That doesn’t mean there aren’t $n$ extensions here, just that you don’t know a priori that there are $n$ non-isomorphic extensions, just $n$ non-equivalent ones.

Comment: The usomorphism type of $G$ cannot be anything other than $Z \oplus Z/mZ$ for some divisor $m$ of $n$. These are the only quotients of $Z \oplus Z$ with the given structure. I don't  understand your question about how one determines $m$ from $f$ $G$ is the codomain of the map $f$, so you would need to know what $G$ was in order to define $f$.